# Why does Chrome have issues with JAWS screen reader?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

Often, I have observed that Chrome and JAWS do not work very well together, while Firefox works seamlessly with JAWS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that Chrome has not implemented the full UA accessibility specification for all types of Web content.

Best browsers for screen reader accessibility are Firefox and IE on Windows and Safari on iOS and OS X and Firefox on Android.

Comment: This was true a year ago. Now as per this https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/assistive-technology-support, they support most screen readers.

Comment: JAWS 12!?!? (what is the sequence of characters for eye-rolling?) That page is so out of date it is laughable

Comment: So you are saying that Chrome officially still does not support any screen readers? It would be great if you could point me to some official references. :)

Comment: nope, I am not saying that, I am simply saying that your reference is not any new information. Chrome has been getting better and does work quite well these days http://html5accessibility.com/ however that does not tell the complete picture because JAWS for example, often goes around the accessibility  APIs to do things that make it work better with IE than other browsers

Comment: Uhhh..... Thanks.  I think now lies a long road of testing which things are better on which combinations. Tired already thinking about it. :(

Comment: As of today: FF+NVDA, JAWS+IE, VO+Safari, FF+Talkback

Comment: ... and yet Google recommends Firefox when using NVDA or JAWS in Google Docs. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6282736